# Help Required for Migration from SharePoint 2010 SP1 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, sp-online

Can anyone guide ( best practices and steps) me about migrating a custom FBA sharepoint application from  SharePoint 2010 SP1 to SharePoint Online

Can we migrate web application to sharepoint online as we used to do in case of attached DB migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Not possible for custom FBA

Comment: Thank you @MiguelIsidoro for reply, any idea how to migrate FBA users to SharePoint Online

Comment: As I know, it's not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short,** the custom FBA can't be migrated to SharePoint Online!

Try the free [SharePoint Migration Tool](https://debug.devoworx.com/34/sharepoint-migration-tool) to move the content, it now supports SharePoint 2010.

Or try other paid migration tools like

- [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration).
- AvePoint.

**Read more at**

- [Migrate to sharepoint online.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

Comment: Thank you for reply bro, please correct me if I am wrong that 

We can't deploy existing custom WSPs on SharePoint Online  

We have to rewrite our existing workflows in SharePoint 2013 before moving to SharePoint online 

do you have any idea, how we can use exising FBA website on SharePoint Online

Comment: @SPDev regarding FBA and custom WSPs, you can’t.  All you can do is migrate the content and 2010 workflows using the migration tools mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but as @GregW said, **custom FBA** can' be migrated to SharePoint Online, Please, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you :)

Comment: Thank you Mohamed and Greg for your reply. I am exploring SharePoint Migration Tool to migrate sites. How to migrate FBA users to SharePoint Online?

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP bro if we migrate site by using SharePoint Migration Tool, our designer created workflow will work and is there any way to migrate user to SharePoint Online